# os.environ.get returns None when called from a different .py file

Tags: python

I have a function set_env_vars(), when called from one file, it works fine, when called from another, returns None

### misc.py

```
import os


def set_env_vars(test):

    print(f"test = {test}")
    if test:
        api_name = os.environ.get("TAPI_NAME")
        api_key = os.environ.get("TAPI_KEY")
        api_passphrase = os.environ.get("TAPI_PASSPHRASE")
        api_secret = os.environ.get("TAPI_SECRET")
        url = "https://openapi-sandbox.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts"
    else:
        api_name = os.environ.get("API_NAME")
        api_key = os.environ.get("API_KEY")
        api_passphrase = os.environ.get("API_PASSPHRASE")
        api_secret = os.environ.get("API_SECRET")
        url = "https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts"
    return api_name, api_key, api_passphrase, api_secret, url
```

### another.py

```
import misc

test = False

api_name, api_key, api_passphrase, api_secret, url = misc.set_env_vars(test)

print(api_name, api_key, api_passphrase, api_secret, url)
exit()
```

output:

```
test = False

None None None None https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts
```

### getbalance.py

```
import misc

test = False

api_name, api_key, api_passphrase, api_secret, url = misc.set_env_vars(test)

print(api_name, api_key, api_passphrase, api_secret, url)
exit()
```

output:

```
test = False

APIname 63key011... APIpassphrase API-secret-31c... https://api.kucoin.com/api/v1/accounts
```

in other words both files/calls are identical, but only getbalance.py works. Why? What am I missing here?
Thanks

Comment: I'd wager your IDE/... is set up in a way that it passes different environment variables depending on what entrypoint you're running.

Comment: How are you executing these?

Comment: are the files in the same folder ?   for example in VS code run everything from one folder....

Comment: The files are in the same folder, to run them I go to a file Ctrl+Shift+F10, as for the IDE setup, an entry point would be the file that I'm running (that's my assumption), I don't understand how a system call act differently just because your calling from a different file..